# Multiple Sub Projects in solution however, deploying one project on Azure's Continuous Delivery

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

Good day:

I'm having an issue understanding Azure's deployment process. I currently have an ASP.NET project with multiple projects:

```
BLAH.OAuth.IdentityServer
BLAH.API
BLAH.AdminPortal.Web
BLAH.Api.Service.Web
```

My intention is only to deploy the `BLAH.API` project. In my **Application Settings** under *App Services*, I've added an Application Settings key/value pair `PROJECT = BLAH.API/BLAH.API.csproj` however, all my projects are still being deployed. See below:

```
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.OAuth.IdentityServer.zip' (25%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.API.zip' (25%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.API.zip' (50%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.API.zip' (75%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.AdminPortal.Web.zip' (33%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.AdminPortal.Web.zip' (66%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.AdminPortal.Web.zip' (100%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.Api.Service.Web.zip' (33%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.Api.Service.Web.zip' (66%)
 Uploading 'drop/BLAH.Api.Service.Web.zip' (100%)
```

Comment: Try to publish the particular application on Azure: https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vsts/appservice/. Then you will get an App Service which has to be mapped in your release definition. Then you can select the particular zip file to deploy: https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vsts/continuousdeployment/.

Comment: Microsoft should probably have a disclaimer that App Service should be used for simple application deployment because, this is a waste of time for deploying complex apps.